# Discord.js v14 don't send image

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord, bots

i have this code that retrieves information from mongoose (MongoDB) and sends a welcome message to a person when they join a Discord server.

```
const { Events, AttachmentBuilder } = require("discord.js");

const welcomeSchema = require("../../Models/welcome.js");

const imageWelcomerSchema = require("../../Models/İmageWelcome.js");

module.exports = {

  name: Events.GuuldMemberAdd,

  async execute(member) {

    try {

      const WelcomeImageGuild = member.guild.id;

      const WelcomeImageData = await imageWelcomerSchema.findOne({ guild: WelcomeImageGuild });

      if (WelcomeImageData) {

        const welcomeChannelId = WelcomeImageData.channel;

        const welcomeImageMsg = WelcomeImageData.msg;

        const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomeChannelId);

        if (welcomeChannel) {

          const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');

          const fetch = (await import('node-fetch')).default;

          const path = require("path");

          const canvas = createCanvas(1536, 1536);

          const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

          const backgroundImage = await loadImage(path.join(__dirname, 'welcome.png'));

          ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

          const personName = member.user.username;

          const personAvatarURL = member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' });

          const avatarBuffer = await fetch(personAvatarURL).then((response) => response.arrayBuffer());

          const avatarImage = await loadImage(avatarBuffer);

          const avatarSize = canvas.width / 2.25;

          const avatarCanvas = createCanvas(avatarSize, avatarSize);

          const avatarCtx = avatarCanvas.getContext('2d');

          avatarCtx.save();

          avatarCtx.beginPath();

          avatarCtx.arc(avatarSize / 2, avatarSize / 2, avatarSize / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);

          avatarCtx.closePath();

          avatarCtx.clip();

          avatarCtx.drawImage(avatarImage, 0, 0, avatarSize, avatarSize);

          avatarCtx.restore();

          const avatarX = (canvas.width - avatarSize) / 20;

          const avatarY = (canvas.height - avatarSize) / 1.55;

          const textY = backgroundImage.height / 0.90;

          ctx.drawImage(avatarCanvas, avatarX, avatarY);

          ctx.font = '60px Arial';

          ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';

          ctx.textAlign = 'center';

          ctx.fillText(personName, backgroundImage.width / 0.80, textY);

          const welcome = new AttachmentBuilder(canvas.toBuffer(), { name : 'welcome.png' });

          welcomeChannel.send({ content: welcomeImageMsg.replace("${member}", member), files: [welcome] });

        }

      }

    } catch (err) {

      console.error(err);

    }

    try {

      const guildID = member.guild.id;

      const welcomeData = await welcomeSchema.findOne({ guild: guildID });

      if (welcomeData) {

        const channelID = welcomeData.channel;

        const welcomeMessage = welcomeData.msg;

        const roleID = welcomeData.role;

        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID);

        const memberRole = member.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);

        if (channel) {

          channel.send(welcomeMessage.replace("${member}", member));

        }

        if (memberRole) {

          member.roles.add(memberRole);

        }

      }

    } catch (err) {

      console.error(err);

    }

  }

};
```

There's a regular message and a welcome message with an image. However, when a member joins the server, it doesn't send the welcome message with the image, and it doesn't even give me any errors in the console. This is strange.

I have downloaded all the required packages. Is there a solution to this?

It is running on discord.js v14 and uses an Event Handler.